# How to link regression unit tests with issue tracker?

Tags: unit-testing, bug-tracking, issue-tracking, regression-testing

I am working on an existing web application (written in .NET) which, surprisingly, has a few bugs in it. We track outstanding in a bug tracker (JIRA, in this case), and have some test libraries in place already (written in NUnit).

What I would like to be able to do is, when closing an issue, to be able to link that issue to the unit-/integration-test that ensures that a regression does not occur, and I would like to be able to expose that information as easily as possible.

There are a few things I can think of off-hand, that can be used in different combinations, depending on how far I want to go:

- copy the URL of the issue and paste it as a comment in the test code;
- add a Category attribute to the test and name it Regressions, so I can select regression tests explicitly and run them as a group (but how to automatically report on which issues have failed regression testing?);
- make the issue number part of the test case name;
- create a custom Regression attribute that takes the URI of the issue as a required parameter;
- create a new custom field in the issue tracker to store the name (or path) of the regression test(s);

The ideal scenario for me would be that I can look at the issue tracker and see which issues have been closed with regression tests in place (a gold star to that developer!), and to look at the test reports and see which issues are failing regression tests.

Has anyone come across, or come up with, a good solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

i fail to see what makes regression tests different from any other tests. why would you want to run only regression tests or everything except regression tests. if regression or non-regression test fails that means this specific functionality is not working and product owner has to decide how critical the problem is. if you stop differentiate tests then simply do code reviews and don't allow any commits without tests.

in case we want to see what tests have been added for specific issues we go to issue tracking system. there are all commits, ideally only one (thanks squashing), issue tracker is connected to git so we can easily browse changed files

in case we want to see (for whatever reason) what issue is related to some specific test/line of code we just give tests a meaningful business name which helps finding any related information. if problem is more technical and we know may need specific issue then we simply add issue number in comment. in case you want to automate retrieval just standardize the format of the comment

another helpful technique is to structure your program correctly. if every functionality has it's own package and tests are packaged and named meaningfully then it's also easy ro find any related code